# How to move/copy a file that has a wildcard in the name in PHP?

Tags: php, file, path

I am trying to copy a file that I download it. The file name is `test1234.txt`, but I want to access it using a wildcard like this: `test*.txt` and after that to move it to another folder (because I don't know how the file name looks like, but I know that the beginning is `test` and the rest is changing every time I download a new one). I tried some codes:

```
$myFile = 'C:/Users/Carl/Downloads/'. date("y-m-d") . '/test*.txt';
$myNewFile = 'C:/Users/Carl/Downloads/'. date("y-m-d").'/text.xml';
    if(preg_match("([0-9]+)", $myFile)) {
        echo 'ok';
        copy($myFile, $myNewFile);
    }
```

I am getting an error because of `*` in `$myFile`. Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: have you tried [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) in this regard?

Comment: yes. The file exist, but I cannot get hold of it (cause the number-partial)

Comment: Please show the code where you actually tried to use `glob()` to resolve the wildcard.

Comment: $myFile= 'C:/Users/Carl/Downloads/'. date("y-m-d") . '/test*.txt';
$myNyFile = 'C:/Users/Carl/Downloads/'.date("y-m-d").'/test.txt';
foreach (glob($myFile) as $fileName) {
 copy($myFile, $myNyFile);
}

Comment: `@mario` Thanks for your comment/help. I know now where I did wrong. If you send it again as an answer, I'll accept it as the best.

Answer (score 2):

```
$myFile= 'C:/Users/Carl/Downloads/'. date("y-m-d") . '/test*.txt';
$myNyFile = 'C:/Users/Carl/Downloads/'.date("y-m-d").'/test.txt'; 

   foreach (glob($myFile) as $fileName) {
      copy($fileName, $myNyFile);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks to `@Ghost` and `@mario`

Answer (score 0):

For complete response, if you want to only move *.txt in NewFolder.

```php
$myFiles  = 'C:/Users/Carl/Downloads/*.txt';
$myFolderDest = 'C:/Users/Carl/NewFolder/'; 

foreach (glob($myFiles) as $file) {
    copy($file, $myFolderDest . basename($file));
}
```